# How to download/find the Saxon samples/cs for .NET

Tags: saxon

This page: https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/samples/dotnetsamples.html refers to a samples/cs directory.   Where can that be found or downloaded?

> The samples/cs directory contains some sample applications written in
>   C#, designed to illustrate use of the Saxon API available in the
>   Saxon.Api namespace.

I downloaded the Saxonica open source from SourceForge (filename=saxon9-9-1-7source.zip) and don't see it in there. I think it contains the "trans-compiled" code from Java.

Answer (score 1):

It's in the latest saxon-resourcesx-x.zip (example saxon-resources9-9.zip).

I finally figured this out by reading the readme99.txt that is also available on SourceForge.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/Saxon-HE/9.9/

After unzipping it, it also a local html copy of the documentation, for example: C:/Saxonica/Resources/doc/dotnetdoc/index.html

Comment: It's also linked at the top of the documentation section you were looking at: https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/samples/ -- sorry you had trouble finding it. I guess we shouldn't assume that people read documentation sequentially but it's hard to see how to avoid such problems.

Comment: Maybe simple text change: "The samples/cs directory contains" to 
"The samples/cs directory (in the resources...zip download) contains".  I'm definitely not a sequential reader.

Comment: The files are also online at https://dev.saxonica.com/repos/archive/opensource/latest9.9/samples/cs/